# What are the ISO, exposure, and aperture settings for single frames from slow-motion video on the iPhone 6?

Tags: exposure, aperture, iso, video, iphone

I filmed a video of myself swinging a tennis racket in slow motion and then used `cv2` to make `jpg`'s of some of the frames, ie. 8 frames from the start of the swing to follow-through evenly spaced, and was going to blend them so that the entire arc of the swing is in one photo.  I used `cv2.addWeighted()`.

I do require this data for the `jpg`s for a school assignment and figured if I knew the default settings for the camera, they would be the same as the frames came from the videos.

Is there a manual or website listing default settings of ISO, exposure and aperture for video mode on iPhone 6?  Not 6s, plain old 6.

Comment: This is on topic as the goal is a single image, not a video.  Video is only being used to generate still frames like a poor man's burst mode.  Also, please do not answer in comments.

Comment: There is no "default exposure settings".  The only thing that is fixed is the aperture as iPhone's do not have  adjustable fstops. The iso and "shutter speed" are determined by the light meter base on the amount of light in the scene being photographed.